# How to set height to the SimpleHistogramBin bin in SimpleHistogramDataset?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I used `setItemsCount()` method to manage height of the bin in my `SimpleHistogram` from `JFreeChart`. Yet, it does something weird: when I set for example 1, it shows 1.4

Besides this method's argument is `Integer`, while I need `double`

Comment: Could you post your example source code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest asking on the [JFreeChart forums](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=3)